# How to handle different python environments correctly using Heroku Pipelines?

Tags: python, heroku

**I'm in the process of adding *Heroku pipelines* to my project and I am seeking suggestions on what is the best way to handle differences between production and non production environments.**

1. For example, I don't want my non production environments to *send emails* to users in system (non production environments have a copy of production database). The only solution I can think of would be to go directly to my email function and do something like:

```
environment_type = app.config['ENV']

def send_email(to, subject, template):
    if environment_type != 'production':
        to = "test_email_account@example.com"
    msg = Message(
        subject,
        recipients=[to],
        html=template,
        sender=app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER']
    )
    mail.send(msg)
```

*Is this a proper solution? Is it possible to just change the email config variables entirely in some way to properly test email functionality for the application without actually sending emails?*

2. Is it appropriate that I just add each heroku add-on (at a cheaper tier) which is used in production, to each other pipeline environment?

Comment: [Please ask only one question at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/248627)

Comment: Specifically, on the mail delivery side, you can use something like [Mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/) in your non-production environments. Use environment variables to modify your settings instead of adding conditionals all over your code.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for this Mailtrap recommendation. This is exactly the type of solution I was seeking!